# NightwatchJS said they ran but no output

Tags: mocha.js, nightwatch.js

Hello I have installed nightwatchjs as an npm package.
I followed the instructions on http://nightwatchjs.org/guide and my nightwatch.js contains the following:

```
require('nightwatch/bin/runner.js');
```

My nightwatch.json looks like so:

```
 "src_folders" : ["test"],
 "output_folder" : "reports",
 "custom_commands_path" : "",
 "custom_assertions_path" : "",
 "page_objects_path" : "",
 "globals_path" : "",
 "test_runner" : {
   "type" : "mocha", "options" : {"ui" : "tdd"}, "reporter" : "list"
 },
 "test_workers": {
   "enabled": true,
   "workers": "auto"
 },

 "selenium" : {
   "start_process" : false,
   "server_path" : "",
   "log_path" : "logs/",
   "host" : "127.0.0.1",
   "port" : 4444,
   "cli_args" : {
     "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
     "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
   }
 },

 "test_settings" : {
   "default" : {
     "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
     "selenium_port"  : 4444,
     "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
     "silent": true,
     "screenshots" : {
       "enabled" : false,
       "path" : ""
     },
     "desiredCapabilities": {
       "browserName": "firefox",
       "javascriptEnabled": true,
       "acceptSslCerts": true
     }
   },

   "chrome" : {
     "desiredCapabilities": {
       "browserName": "chrome",
       "javascriptEnabled": true,
       "acceptSslCerts": true
     }
   }
 }
}
```

When I run my tests I see

```
[ cmavromoustakos ~/] ✔ node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch --env chrome
Started child process for: routes/routesTest

  >> routes/routesTest finished.


[ cmavromoustakos ~/nightwatch-tes... ] ✔
```

I do not see anything in the logs or anything else that lets me know the tests have run.

Comment: Can you provide the routes/routesTest test too?